# Firebase cloud storage, TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I try to run this code.

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage');


const apiKey = '<KEY>';
const projectID = '<ID>';
const dbName = 'db';
const bucketName = '<BUCKET>.appspot.com';
const keyFile = './firebase.json';

const config = {
    apiKey: apiKey,
    authDomain: `${projectID}.firebaseapp.com`,
    databaseURL: `https://${dbName}.firebaseio.com`,
    storageBucket: 'test-55625.appspot.com'
};

const gcsConfig = {
    projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123',
    keyFilename: keyFile
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

So, I wanna use a a cloud storage, but I can't.
I have tried next tips:

```
firebase.storage()
app.storage()
firebase.app().storage()
```

Or anything like this.
So I tried to use this library too
`const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage');`
But I can just download an empty file and can't upload file to storage.
May be docs is deprecaetd, may be I can't understand something, or I use wrong keyfile!
Thanks for you attention.

Comment: your `storageBucket` should be `gs://test-55625.appspot.com`. can you console `app` to see what you get